# Why is this variable undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extend the JavaScript on a page I maintain to apply some formatting as the calendar section of the page is loaded. There's a prexisting function called `InitCalendar(month)` that loads the section in response to a click.

The calendar is written as a list of days. I'd like to alter the height of `<div>` elements containing events based on the number of events per day. If there are two rather than one event in a day, each event needs to shrink to fit, etc.

So the intended algorithm is to:

- Get an array of `<li>`, the days in the calendar.
- For each `<li>`, get a array of the `<div>` elements it contains
- Set the appropriate height based on the length of the `div` array.

My effort is failing with this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Here's my code:

```
function setHeights(n, string, elems) {
   // start at 1 to avoid the first element in the array.
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       var x = elems[i];
       x.style.height = string;
   };
};

function eventHeights() {
    var ls = $(".calendar").children().children();
    var n = ls.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var divs = ls[i].children;

        switch (divs.length) {
        case 4:
            setHeights(4, "27px", divs);
        case 3:
            setHeights(3, "52px", divs);
        };
     };
};

function InitCalendar(month) 
{
    // ... Some preexisting code to load the calendar section ...

    eventHeights();
}
```

Here's a fragment of the HTML to show the structure I'm working with:

```
<div class="calendar">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
       <div>...</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Help figuring this out greatly appreciated!

Comment: Few comments: Why is your loop starting from 1? Should be starting from 0. It looks like you're not passing an array into setHeights. `ls.children` is not an array

Comment: It's starting from 1 because the first `<div>` in each list should be skipped (it holds the day number, not an event). Can you clarify your second point? `ls.children()` seemed to give me a different error...

Comment: If your loop doesn't start at 0, there should be some comments about it, don't keep it a mistery. `ls.children` returns `undefined`, therefore you can't call `ls.children()` you probably want to use `$(ls[i].children())`, or `ls[i].childNodes` but that could contain text nodes that you don't are about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are 0 based, so the for loop in `setHeights` is incorrect. Note the change in the assignment of `i` and the change from `<=` to `<` in the condition:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var x = elems[i];
    x.style.height = string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1, not from 1 to length. In `eventHeights` you're doing it right, but in `setHeight`, the index is wrong.

Comment: Starting at 1 is intentional, actually--I need to skip the first element in the array. I'll kill the <= and see how that works...

Comment: Ok. In that case, the 1 is ok, but `<=` should still be `<`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in your :

```
function setHeights(n, string, elems) {
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       var x = elems[i];
       x.style.height = string;
   };
};
```

n is the length, supposing a length of 4, you iterate from 1 to 4, and 4 is an invalid index since they are 0 based. Should be 0 to 3, so try changing it to :

```
function setHeights(n, string, elems) {
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       var x = elems[i];
       x.style.height = string;
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

It's looping through an array, which starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

There's another problem with this code, and while it wasn't the cause of the error message, it made debugging brutal. The `switch` statement I had lacks `break` statements in its `case` entries. So even with the `i<=n` bug fixed, my code as written will iterate through the length 4 arrays, setting heights to 27 px, and then move on to `case 3:`, setting the second and third div heights to 52 px.

Not at all what I intended, and the cause of much confusion.